# Trying to click on Login Button but it says element is not interactable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to click on Login button using nightwatch and it says element is not interactable.

```
module.exports = {

  before(browser) {
    browser.maximizeWindow();
  },

  'MyWrkOuts Login Test#1' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://www.mywrkouts.com/')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000)
      .useXpath().click("//*[contains(text(),'Login')]")
      .pause(5000);
  },

  after(browser, done) {
    browser.end(() => {
      console.info('*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*');
      console.info('*-- Clossing session... Good bye! --*');
      console.info('*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*');
      done();
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the error message:

```
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js Results for:  MyWrkOuts Login Test#1 
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js ✔ Element <body> was visible after 33 milliseconds. 
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js Error while running .clickElement() protocol action: element not interactable 
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js  
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js   An error occurred while running .click() command on <//*[contains(text(),'Login')]>: element not interactable 
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5) 
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js ✖ [Mywrkoutslogin] MyWrkOuts Login Test#1 (6.871s) 
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js *--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--* 
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js *-- Clossing session... Good bye! --* 
 tests/mywrkoutslogin.js *--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Hi @Krishna A can you increase the wait from 2000 to say 5000 or 6000 and may be give a try.